# How to syn form action in Facebook iframe canvas?

Tags: facebook, iframe, post

When I submit a form using method "POST" and full canvas callback Url action inside Facebook iframe canvas, I cannot get the form elements in the request.

Can anyone give me some help on this?

page code:

```
<form action="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="myvar" value="v" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You got my love just for the target="_top" part. It saved my day. It prevents "Go to Facebook" redirect page from appearing.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question i think that
you are in an IFRAME... so why use a facebook url for the action?

simply put in the action parameter the url of your web application (not the facebook url, but the url of the canvas) something like http://www.yourhost.it/your_fb_app/process.php/aspx

hope this help (and hope to have understood your problem)